# time of ping to google for check internet availability

Tags: android

i really need help
i try this code but when internet is okay there is no problem but when the device is is connected to the wifi but there is not available internet it answer need a lot of time and its too slow
how can i reduce that time?

```
public Boolean isOnline() {
    try {
        Process p1 = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 www.google.com");
        int returnVal = p1.waitFor();
        boolean reachable = (returnVal==0);
        return reachable;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why are you relying upon a command (`ping`) that might not exist on all devices, instead of simply making an HTTPS request for your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the default timeout for ping using
`ping -c 1 -W 1 www.google.com`

This sets the timeout to 1 sec.
The default timeout is 4 seconds.